# What's the quickest quicksort - League table for sorting algorithms?

Tags: sorting, quicksort, mergesort, heapsort, bucket-sort

I was trying to optimize my quicksort for performance. For 4M (1<<22) integer items (4 bytes each), it takes a parallel quicksort algorithm 0.5 (0.499703) second to sort on a system which can support 72 concurrent threads (72 cores). I'm interested to learn of efficient ways to further optimize my parallel quicksort. Also, interested in comparing with other sorting algorithms if there's a league table for all sorting algorithms, given a certain workload?

Comment: It's all about Big Oh, and a priori knowledge of the key set

Comment: It was all so much easier when sorts were all performed on one thread.  Now that developers are loading up their multi-cores with chunks of work, optimization of algotigthm and its metadata are becoming heavily architecture-dependent - cache sizes etc.  I haven't seen much wok on that yet, or any tables/graphs/charts/algorithms that might suggest the best sort algo and metadata on various systems.

Comment: I sued random key set generated by rand(). Indeed, Big(O) is important, also concurrency. Some algorithms are less likely to be parallelized efficiently. Some others, such as smoothsort, has the best big O properties, but hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no canonical leaderboard for sorting algorithms. The performance of a sorting algorithm depends on a lot of different factors - the input distribution you get, the size of the inputs, the choice of programming language, the type and settings of compiler used, the number of cores, the ambient temperature in the room, the operating system, etc.

As for your other question - how to optimize your quicksort - without seeing your code, it's hard to say for sure. Here are a list of common quicksort optimizations that you may want to try out.

1. Switching to a faster sort on small inputs: insertion sort runs in quadratic time, but for small inputs it can be much, much faster than quicksort. It's not uncommon for quicksort implementations to switch to insertion sort once the number of elements to sort drops below a certain threshold, which can significantly decrease runtimes.
2. Adding introspection. Introsort is a fast variant of quicksort that keeps track of the recursion depth and switches to heapsort when it looks like the algorithm is degenerating. This guarantees that the runtime will be O(n log n) and incurs only a small cost if this case isn't triggered.
3. Using a better partitioning algorithm. Dual-pivot quicksort has recently appeared on the scene as an alternative to the traditional partitioning algorithms. It has better performance on many inputs. Also, consider using a partitioning scheme that gracefully handles duplicate elements if you expect that you'll get inputs with lots of duplicates.
4. Introduce tail-call elimination. Many quicksort implementations fire off two recursive calls for the two subarrays that need to be sorted, but it's not actually necessary to do this. You can fire off one recursive call, then treat the second call as a tail call by overwriting the parameters to the initial call and putting the whole thing in a while loop.